# What to name package and their facade classes?

Tags: design-patterns, naming, packages, naming-standards

I'm using a some C++ Facade classes like this:

[image]

Suppose that there is package named "SubSystem" with a lot of classes inside, like in the picture above.

I cannot name the package of the facade class "SubSystem", because there is already a namespace with the same name.

What is a good standard or practice to name Facade classes for subsystems?

Comment: What is the purpose of the facade class? What does it represent? This will give you a hint to the name.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) has examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is now basically unanswerable since the linked image was deleted. To avoid such problems in the future, please upload important images to the Stack Exchange image host. I'm voting to close this question as unclear.

Answer (score -3):

**Suggestion**: You can create your on pattern to name a façade. Example: use the Letter "F" to all façace classes. Then this one will be FSubSystem class.

Comment: This being your first answer. Try to put context of further explanation to make it more complete. Adding the reasoning that lead you to this conclussion will be welcomed.